# Fix path used by shebang #!/usr/bin/perl and #!/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl

Tags: centos, perl, path, shebang

I can't find anyone that can help me fix this issue. after a recent centos update my CGI scrips that use:

```
#!/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

are trying to use an old perl version 5.16.3

but they should be using the current cpanel version 5.30.0

if i login to ssh and run

`/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl -v` i get  5.30.0

so i need to edit the path that the shebang use and it to to `/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl`

help ?

Comment: The path that you mention you'd like to use seem so be the same as the one you say it's using.

Comment: ya :) but it's not .. when the script runs using the  shebangs it uses some wierd 5.16.3 version as opposed to what it should be using so i figure that the path that the shebangs command use got edited during this server update

Comment: No, the `#!`-line in the file is the interpreter it will use, assuming you don't invoke the scripts with an _explicit_ interpreter. If you do, you can have anything in the `#!`-line, and it would not matter what that path said as it would be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If you find that the `#!`-line in a Perl script does not seem to take effect (which seems to be the case here), then it's likely because the scripts are being invoked with an *explicit* interpreter, as in

```
perl somescript.pl
```

In this case, the `#!`-line would be completely ignored, and the *actual* `perl` binary used would be the first one found in `$PATH`.

If you can change the way that the scripts are being invoked, then you would ideally change that to drop the explicit `perl` command. This would make the `#!`-lines in the scripts take effect (assuming the scripts are executable).

Alternatively, you would arrange for the `$PATH` variable so that the first `perl` binary found is the one that you know that you want to use.  For example, you may want to set

```
PATH=/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin:$PATH
```

for the environment in which the CGI script executes. This would solve the issue *unless* the invocation is with `usr/bin/perl` explicitly.  Since there is no indication in the question what web server software or framework is in use, or how it's configured to run Perl scripts, that's all I can say.

Answer (score -2):

Found the fix:

in SSH as Root:

```
cd /usr/bin

rm -f perl

ln -s /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl .
```

This sets the shebang for both

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

and

```
#!/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl
```

to use the cpanel updated perl found in:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl
```

Comment: Note that by manually removing the `/usr/bin/perl` executable and replacing it with a different `perl` executable, you have now likely broken other things on your setup.

Comment: And the next time the perl package gets updated, it’ll *fix* the /usr/bin/perl file to be the packaged version and not the symlink into /usr/local/cpanel/...